# How to fix when I update composer on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I trying to run my laravel 5 project on laravel 8. When I am trying to update my laravel composer. I am fetching this kind of problem.

[image: Here the problem is]

Comment: You need to go through every package and make sure you have set the correct dependency versions for laravel 8

Comment: A good way suggestion if you're updating a real application is update version by version instead jump from laravel 5 to laravel 8. So you can prevent a kind of errors from depedencies.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have enough coverage on the updates and changes that you need you have to look at at least 2 parts.

#### PHP

- There will be breaking changes to the languages and updates that you would need to make in order to ensure consistent behaviours across the PHP versions. The following link should have the relevant guides to help you with this.
- E.g. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

#### Laravel

- Look at the `/upgrade` portion of the Laravel documentation. You should be able to find them at [https://laravel.com/docs/{version}/upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/%7Bversion%7D/upgrade)
- E.g. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade

Given the large number of version jumps, you might want to consider re-writing the application in a fresh Laravel 9 (or latest) installation.

Best of luck!